# How to use Detect Apex Runtime Context with RequestId and Quiddity

Tags: apex, winter21

This is part of the [Winter '21 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_Runtime_Detection.htm) and I was wondering what are the use cases for this?

Can I use it with the current debug logs to get a better picture of a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider below example whenever we create a contact we need to identify synchronous/asynchronous unknown processes.

```
trigger testing on Contact (after insert) {
  Map<Id, Quiddity> mapIdToQuiddity = new Map<Id, Quiddity>();
  set<Id> setActId = new Set<Id>();
  List<Account>lstAct = new List<Account>();
  Request reqInfo = Request.getCurrent();  //Get info about the current request
  system.debug('Req →' + reqInfo);
  String currentRequestId = reqInfo.getRequestId();  //Universally unique identifier for this request
//Same as requestId in splunk or REQUEST_ID in event monitoring
  system.debug('currentRequestId →' + currentRequestId);
  Quiddity currentType = reqInfo.getQuiddity();  //enum representing how Apex is running.
  system.debug('Quiddity →' + currentType);
  for (Contact oCon : trigger.new) {
    mapIdToQuiddity.put(oCon.accountid, reqInfo.getQuiddity());
    setActId.add(oCon.accountid);
  }
  system.debug('setActId:' + setActId);
  for (Account oEachAcc : [select id,Quidity__c from Account where id in :setActId]) {
    system.debug('mapIdToQuiddity.get(oEachAcc.id):' + mapIdToQuiddity.get(oEachAcc.id));
    oEachAcc.Quidity__c = string.valueof(mapIdToQuiddity.get(oEachAcc.id));
    lstAct.add(oEachAcc);
  }
  Integer count = lstAct?.size();
  if (count > 0) {
    update lstAct;
  }
}
```

You can use debug logs.

[image]

Thanks,